# Temporarily wildcard import / readability of numpy formulas

Tags: python, import, contextmanager

When using `numpy` there's a lot of `np.*` in the code, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.sin(np.abs(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)))
```

This clutters formulas and makes them less readable. One could come around this using a wildcard import

```
from numpy import *
y = sin(abs(linspace(0, 2*pi)))
```

However, wildcard import is almost always a bad idea.

I'm wondering if there is the possibility to make a wildcard import into a context limited to the formula (or math code block). This would maintain readability and would limit the namespace pollution to a small code area which can be controlled more easily. I would like something like this:

```
with import_wildcard(numpy):
    y2 = sin(abs(linspace(0, 2*pi)))
```

Questions:

1. Is there some language construct to allow this.
2. Is the request itself reasonable or am I overlooking a potential problem?

Comment: If you import with the wildcard in a scope you get: `SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level`.

Comment: `from numpy import sin, abs, linespace, pi`

Comment: Not quite sure I agree that a prefixed `np.` makes things less readable. In fact, I'd say it does the opposite -- the reader doesn't need to check where `abs` came from. Is it `np.abs` or  `builtins.abs`?

Comment: @erip Thanks for the feedback. You're right that it's more clear if the imported objects are specified explicitly. I've added another solution which temporarily promotes specified objects to the global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 2: Temporarily promote specified objects

Based on the feedback, here's another approach which is more explicit. Instead of makeing a temporary wildcard import, we only temporarily promote specified objects to the global namespace.

```
class global_context(object):
    def __init__(self, *objects):
        """Return a context manager that has the given objects available in the global namespace.

        You can directly pass in an object if it has a __name__, otherwise use the string name.
        """
        def parse_object(obj):
            if isinstance(obj, str):
                ns, name = obj.split('.')
                return name, getattr(globals()[ns], name)
            else:
                return obj.__name__, obj
        self.identifiers = dict(parse_object(o) for o in objects)
        self.globals_backup = {}

    def __enter__(self):
        _globals = globals()
        for name, fn in self.identifiers.items():
            if name in _globals:
                self.globals_backup[name] = _globals[name]
        _globals.update(self.identifiers)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        _globals = globals()
        for name in self.identifiers:
            if name not in self.globals_backup:
                del _globals[name]
        _globals.update(self.globals_backup)
        self.globals_backup.clear()
```

Usage:

```
import numpy as np
with global_context(np.sin, np.abs, np.linspace, 'np.pi'):
    y = sin(abs(linspace(0, 2*pi)))
```

I'll leave the first solution as well so that advantages and disadvantages of each approach can be discussed more easily, and people can vote for each solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1: Temporary wildcard import:

```
class import_wildcard(object):
    """Contextmanager to temporary import a package content into the global namespace."""
    def __init__(self, packagename):
        self.packagename = packagename
        self.package = __import__(self.packagename, globals(), locals())
        self.globals_backup = {}

    def __enter__(self):
        _globals = globals()
        for name in self.package.__dict__:
            if name in _globals:
                self.globals_backup[name] = _globals[name]
        _globals.update(self.package.__dict__)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        _globals = globals()
        for name in self.package.__dict__:
            if name not in self.globals_backup:
                del _globals[name]
        _globals.update(self.globals_backup)
        self.globals_backup.clear()


with import_wildcard('numpy'):
    y = sin(abs(linspace(0, 2*pi)))
```

So far, I've not come across significant drawbacks. Except of course variables defined outside the context with the same name as some function in numpy will not be accessible in the context.